# Repeating grouping headers in the bipublisher layout

Tags: bi-publisher

I have to group records based on a fund and the page should have the header as fund and when data flows into next page the header should also be present.

I have grouped the data and displayed the header in first but I am unable to repeat the header when data moves to multiple pages. I cannot use RTF layouts, I need a solution within Bipublisher layout design.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use RTF Layouts?

Comment: We need BI Publisher Add-Ins to be installed in MS Word in order to load the XML data and to create a rtf template. which apparently my office does not provide also we require desktop version of Bipublisher.

Comment: You can download BI Publisher Desktop free from Oracle's website. You also do not technically need the add-in, BI Publisher logic is stored, usually, in help-text part of field elements. Standard Word will display that information in the field properties. You can also put logic outside of these as plain-text within the document. It will look messy, but is doable. It will get replaced/eliminated similar to PHP in HTML.

Comment: I have requested for the Bi publisher desktop at my office and we are getting installed,yay!,(we are not supposed to install anything on our own at office).Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Good luck! Getting and installing the right one can be tricky. Also, I always configure mine to be "backward compatible" else bad things tend to happen. (Word, Add-Ins, Tools, Build, Form Field Size, Backward Compatible)